# output beautifulsoup data into a csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to output my beautifulsoup data into a csv with 2 columns: 1. Title, 2. Description

So the Title column should have soup.Title and then the Description should be the print statements that are in the loop that starts with for x in courselinks...

```
**#This is what I tried:**
with open('newcsv.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow('Title')

for x in courselinks[0:3]:
    data = requests.get(("http:"+x)
    soup = bs(data.text)
    print soup.title #This I want in the Title column
    for header in soup.find_all(text='Description'):
        nextNode = header.parent
        while True:
            nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
            if nextNode is None:
                break
            if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
                print (nextNode.get_text(strip=True).strip().encode('utf-8')) **#This I want in the Description column**
            if isinstance(nextNode, NavigableString):
                print (nextNode.strip().encode('utf-8')) **#This I want in the Description column**
            if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
                if nextNode.name == "h2":
                    break
```

This is what I want...
[image]

Comment: Don't you want the lines beginning with `for x in courselink[0:3]:` indented?

Comment: yea sorry formatting issue, they are indented on my original

Comment: yea formatting issue, they are in my original code. I just want the two print statements to write to the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a row to a csv, you are just writing an array or list to the file. Each value in the list or array is a value in the row.  If you want the first item in the array in the first column you put it in the first place, the 0 index.  Each subsequent item in that row is a subsequent index in the array/list.

```
for x in courselinks[0:3]:
    data = requests.get(("http:"+x)
    soup = bs(data.text)
    current_row = [soup.title,''] #This I want in the Title column
    for header in soup.find_all(text='Description'):
        current_row[1] = ''
        nextNode = header.parent
        while True:
            nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
            if nextNode is None:
                writer.writerow(current_row)
                break
            if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
                current_row[1] += nextNode.get_text(strip=True).strip().encode('utf-8') **#This I want in the Description column**
            if isinstance(nextNode, NavigableString):
                current_row[1] += nextNode.strip().encode('utf-8') **#This I want in the Description column**
            if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
                if nextNode.name == "h2":
                    writer.writerow(current_row)
                    break
```

Comment: Thats still putting the soup.title in the same column as the description. I want 2 columns: Title & Description each title has one description (which is a combination of the two print statements). I have around 1000 soup.titles

Comment: I've added a photo to my original post. Where it says 'Bunch of text here'. That should be a combination of my two print lines. Based on your code, things are saving text to each column in the csv and the title is not appearing. Basically  my for loop is going through 50 titles and then getting the description for each of them.

Comment: I've edited further, I had been overwriting the wrong portion.  Basically, what you want in the first column of each row is the title: `current_row = [soup.title, '']` and then you just add the other text to the other portion `current_row[1] += other_text`.  The current version should reflect this change.

Comment: I dont see what was changed

Comment: I added an explanation of how to add things in the columns in csv's, not sure if that helps you to see what you need to do or not, but at this point i'm not seeing the disconnect.